# Go SHA-256 hash differs from Java SHA-256 hash

Tags: java, hash, go, sha

If I generate the SHA-256 hash in the language "GO", I get a different byte-Array compared to the Java equivalent.

This is the GO version:

```
fmt.Println(getSha256([]byte("5nonce=5")))
```

The resulting array looks like:

```
41 79 186 235 199 123 95 226 16 59 51 161 112 245 192 50 21 66 180 250 179 109 153 18 233 148 16 237 156 69 163 150]
```

This one should do the same in Java code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

md.update("5nonce=5".getBytes()); 
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

But results in this byte array

```
[41, 79, -70, -21, -57, 123, 95, -30, 16, 59, 51, -95, 112, -11, -64, 50, 21, 66, -76, -6, -77, 109, -103, 18, -23, -108, 16, -19, -100, 69, -93, -106]
```

Why are they different? How do I need to change the java version to work exactly like the Go version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Why are they different?

They're not, really. They're the same bits. It's just that Java doesn't have unsigned bytes - so any byte with the top bit set is negative. In every case like that, you'll see that Java result = Go result - 256.

If you convert both byte arrays to hex or base64, you'll see same results.

Comment: Thanks, converting them to base64 makes it a lot easier to compare them and they are ideed identical.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is the Go code](http://play.golang.org/p/tOdeYraWcK) which would produce the same result:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "crypto/sha256"

func main() {
    sum224 := sha256.Sum256([]byte("5nonce=5"))
    s := make([]int8, sha256.Size)
    for i := range sum224 {
        s[i] = int8(sum224[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d", s)
}

[41 79 -70 -21 -57 123 95 -30 16 59 51 -95 112 -11 -64 50 21 66 -76 -6 -77 109 -103 18 -23 -108 16 -19 -100 69 -93 -106]
```

The [fmt doc](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) does mention:

> There is no '`u`' flag. Integers are printed unsigned if they have unsigned type.

Since [Numeric Types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) defines:

- `byte`        alias for `uint8`
- `uint8`       the set of all unsigned  8-bit integers (0 to 255)
- `int8`        the set of all signed  8-bit integers (-128 to 127)

That is why you would need to convert `byte` (unsigned) into signed `int8` to see the same.

---

If you add base64 encoding (see [golang playground](http://play.golang.org/p/J6DRB54jU9)), you can get a result easier to compare:

```
import "encoding/base64"

res := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(sum224[:]))
fmt.Println(res)
```

That returns:

```
KU+668d7X+IQOzOhcPXAMhVCtPqzbZkS6ZQQ7ZxFo5Y=
```